# Php table associative

Tags: php

I need to make a form . First I need a select that 
let you choose group1 ,group 2 or both.
Second, there is an checkbox that ask you if you want to show the people in the groups who failed their class.

```
<?php
$NotesGroupe1 = array(
 "HARG200181" => array("Guillaume", "Harvey", "M", 36, 90, 70, 76),
 "CHAM010283" => array("Marc-André", "Charpentier", "M", 34, 80, 73, 96),
 "TREV290991" => array("Valérie", "Tremblay", "F", 26, 70, 71, 69),
 "PELL180584" => array("Laurence", "Pelletier", "F", 30, 65, 89, 76),
 "MALF110194" => array("Francis", "Maltais", "M", 20, 61, 50, 59),
 "GAUM220654" => array("Martine", "Gauthier", "F", 60, 65, 40, 76),
);
$NotesGroupe2 = array(
 "GIRM230383" => array("Marc-Olivier", "Girard", "M", 31, 75, 85, 56),
 "TREM300878" => array("Michel", "Tremblay", "M", 36, 50, 50, 55),
 "POID250468" => array("Diane", "Poitras", "F", 46, 61, 75, 59),
 "LEML180586" => array("Laurence", "Lemieux", "F", 31, 80, 89, 100),
 "VANL130395" => array("Jeff", "Van Cleef", "M", 19, 61, 68, 33)
);
```

After that, You need a radiobutton that tells you if you want the grade of 
   Males or Females or both.

```
    <form method="GET">
            <div class="menu">
                <?php include 'menu.php';?>
            </div>
            Choisir une groupe : 
            <select name="groupe">
                            <option value='0'>Groupe 1</option>
                            <option value='1'>Groupe 2</option>
                            <option value='3'>Groupe 1 & 2</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            Affichez seulement les notes des élèves en situation d'échec.
            <input type="checkbox" name="echec" value="selectionner"/><br>
            Affichez hommes & femmes : <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="M|F" checked="checked"/>
            Affichez seulement les hommes : <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="M"/>
            Affichez seulement les femmes : <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="F"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Soumettre"/>
            <?php
            require_once("tableaux.php");
              if(isset($_GET["groupe"])&& isset($_GET["sexe"])){
                    $groupeNumber = $_GET["groupe"];
                    $sexe = $_GET["sexe"];
                    $pregSexe = "/" . $sexe . "/im"; 
                    $groupe = "";
                    if($groupeNumber == 0){
                            $groupe = $NotesGroupe1;
                    }else if ($groupeNumber == 1){
                            $groupe = $NotesGroupe2;    
                    }
                    else{
                            $groupe=$NotesGroupe1+$NotesGroupe2;
                    }
                    if ( preg_match($pregSexe, $sexe)){

                    }else if ( preg_match($pregSexe, $sexe)  ){

                    }
                    else if( preg_match($pregSexe, $sexe){

                    }

                    if(isset($_GET["echec"]){
                        $echec = $_GET["echec"];
                        if ($echec == true){

                        }
                        else{   
                        }
                    }
              }
            ?>
```

I didn't finish the code , I can't seem to relate the failed grades in the groups relating to the sexs. I can'T modify the arrays so is there anything that could help me. thanks

Comment: "I can'T modify the arrays"  Why not?

Comment: @PatrickQ Seems like a homework question?

Comment: It actually is. I can't modify what  he gave me on the first code table.

Comment: You need to filter the array `$groupe` using `$pregSexe`?

Comment: I need to know what sexe they choose to see which person they want to look at.

Comment: @ΞngjellBislimi You already know this in `$sexe` variable.

Comment: but then how i can show the group i want . if they take M or F or Both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) with a custom function to reduce the array according to your regular expression.

```
$NotesGroupe1 = array(
 "HARG200181" => array("Guillaume", "Harvey", "M", 36, 90, 70, 76),
 "CHAM010283" => array("Marc-André", "Charpentier", "M", 34, 80, 73, 96),
 "TREV290991" => array("Valérie", "Tremblay", "F", 26, 70, 71, 69),
 "PELL180584" => array("Laurence", "Pelletier", "F", 30, 65, 89, 76),
 "MALF110194" => array("Francis", "Maltais", "M", 20, 61, 50, 59),
 "GAUM220654" => array("Martine", "Gauthier", "F", 60, 65, 40, 76),
);
$groupe = $NotesGroupe1 ;
$sexe = 'F'; // arbitrary value but come from your $_POST.
$pregSexe = '/'.$sexe.'/im' ; // eg. '/F/im', '/M/im', or  '/M|F/im' 
$groupe = array_filter($groupe, function($element) use ($pregSexe) {
    return preg_match($pregSexe, $element[2]) ;
});
print_r($groupe);
```

The function is an anonymous function and `$pregSexe` is passed on it using `use()` to be accessible on its scope. This function returns a boolean: `true` to keep, `false` to reject.

In the code above, only the elements of the array with the 3rd key `"F"` remain in the final array.

```
Array (
    [TREV290991] => Array ([0] => Valérie [1] => Tremblay [2] => F [3] => 26 [4] => 70 [5] => 71 [6] => 69 )
    [PELL180584] => Array ([0] => Laurence [1] => Pelletier [2] => F [3] => 30 [4] => 65 [5] => 89 [6] => 76 )
    [GAUM220654] => Array ([0] => Martine [1] => Gauthier [2] => F [3] => 60 [4] => 65 [5] => 40 [6] => 76 )
)
```

Comment: i've just seen your answer, i'm sorry and thank you for taking the time to answer!